# Getting value of linkDistance in d3

Tags: d3.js

I want to print the value that my link distance returned in the console but when i do that I get only 20 which is the default value.I studied that if linkDistance is a function then ideally it gets called every time when layout starts so I should get the 2 different values that I am returning in console but it is not the case.
Any idea?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pria_3/77a5svf6/3/embedded/result/      Refer the code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pria_3/77a5svf6/3/

Comment: You are printing `d3.layout.force().linkDistance()` which will return 20 by default since it is a new instance. You will have to use the force layout instance you used via the variable `force`.

Comment: I used force.linkDistance() It gives me complete function definition where i just want the value returned.Any other way to print?

Comment: Of course it will return the function only.Try to put a static value to the linkDistance. `force.linkDistance()` will return that value then. If it is a function the linkDistance depends on the nodes that are being connected, right? What do you a expect as the output? Is it the distances between current node and nodes connected to them? Why don't you use the same function you used for calculating linkDistance here then?